# Getting and Setting Pitch Yaw Roll from/to OpenGL modelview matrix

Tags: c, opengl, matrix

I'm fairly sure the set code should look like this:

```
function setPYR(float pitch, float yaw, float roll) {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(pitch, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(roll, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

How can I get the pitch, yaw and roll from the current modelview matrix?

Comment: Why not just save them in variables, and then return the saved values?

Comment: In most cases I do not have them in the first place to save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look at [The Matrix and Quaternions FAQ](http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q37).

Comment: This link suggest that Q36 gives the proper way to go from Euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll) to the modelview matrix. However, if I'm not mistaken, this approach has issues due to gimbal lock, right? (At least I just run into gimbal lock problems when implementing according to Q36.) Wouldn't it be better to go this route: *Q60. How do I convert Euler rotation angles to a quaternion?* and then *Q54. How do I convert a quaternion to a rotation matrix?*? Maybe [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut08%20Quaternions.html) may help as well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#setRotateEulerM(float[],%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float)